# Detecting Div end with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I want to detect a div (dynamic content div) end, when user scroll down the scroller in jquery.
i use this code but it will call jquery function by each pixel of scroll down.

```
$j(function($j){
      $j('.products').bind('scroll', function()
        {
          if($j(this).scrollTop() + $j(this).innerHeight()>=$j(this)[0].scrollHeight)
          {
            alert('end reached');
            $j.fn.productsload();
          } 
        });
    }
  );
```

But i want to alert and call function when the div end reach otherwise not alert anything.!
Any idea will be appreciated :) ....Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find a solution for this problem, by finding the div height from top to div end, and also finding the total page scroll by .scrollTop() + (window).height() and compare these two values like.

```
$j(function($j){
      $j('.products').bind('scroll', function()
        {
            var elem = $j('products');
            var divend = elem[0].scrollHeight + elem.offset().top; // full height of div (from top and actual div height).
            var pagescroll = $j(this).scrollTop() + $j(this).height(); // Total page scrolled.

              if(divend <= pagescroll)
              {
                  alert(" Div End reached! ");
                  alert("Full DIV height: "+divend+" Scroll page Height: "+pagescroll); 
              }
       }
   }
```

SO this is  the solution of finding div end when scrolling down by jquery.....
Cheer!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the exact syntax but you can use `.scrollTop()` which gets the height of the content that has already been scrolled beyond view.

```
if ((divsContentHeight - actualDivHeight) == scrollTopValue)
{
  //Tada, you have reached end of scrolling
}
```

Comment: Thanx, conqenator: but can you explain it little bit! because i don't understand the divHeight which is dynamic (i.e: change with products). and visibleArea, ScollTopValue.?

Comment: By `divHeight` i meant the height of the content within the div. By `visibleArea` i meant the specified height i.e. and `scrollTopValue` is the value computed by `.scrollTop()`. I will edit my answer.

Comment: But the div height is dynamic, can you clarify your answer..thanx.

Comment: You can get that by doing `.height()` then? and the content within the div or its wrapper would have some height? you can get that by doing `.css('height')` maybe?

Comment: This is right that .scrollTop() is the key where we can detect the end of div reach. But the div can be anywhere in page. so how can we exactly detect the end of DIV... thanx.

Comment: Use `$(element).offset().top` to detect position from document top, maybe.  I must say, I dint understand your question.(in the comment)

Comment: Thanx, for your suggestions. Now this is so easy, i have post the answer.

Comment: Thanks. You could also mark mine as the answer and post the relavant implementaion in the comments(instead of a separate answer)  :)